# Looking for a great Linux code editor that has auto-indent AND auto-outdent

Tags: linux, html, text-editors, javascript, jquery

I code primarily in jQuery/JavaScript, and I'm looking for a text editor for Linux that has auto-indent and auto-outdent (seems to be tough to find that). Any suggestions? I've checked Gedit, Cream, vim, Bluefish. None of them seem to have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) has auto-outdent on close brace.

Comment: Whoa, love it! Really nice editor, great features too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Vim does indent your code (and it also has a "smartindent" feature which might be equivalent to auto-outdenting. I've never tried it myself but you can do this in your ~/.vimrc

```
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

If not, Vim has hundreds of plugins which might get that accomplished.

Comment: Cool! Now, can I get Cream to use smartindent as well? Cream doesn't seem to do the auto-outdent

Comment: According to this: http://cream.sourceforge.net/faq.html Cream should be picking up on the ~/.vimrc file automatically. Unless, you've turned it off. Try going through your preferences and taking a look as I'm not 100% sure of this :)

Comment: Nowadays `Vim` does in- and outdenting with indentation rules defined for every file type. These indent files can be found in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/<ft>.vim`. To make it work, you have to place `filetype indent on` in your `vimrc`. I'd guess Cream has that already in place, though. (See `:help filetype-indent-on`.)